# Do $P(X\cup F)=P(E) \cup P(F)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

Given $E$ and $F$ two sets 
And $P$ is part of set

Do $P(E \cup F)=P(E) \cup P(F)$ ?

$X\in P(E \cup F)\ \Longrightarrow\ X\in P(E)$  or $X\in P(F)$

Im stuck here.

Comment: $P$ is part of set?

Comment: What is "part of a set"?

Comment: @avid19 A€P(E) <=> A is subset of E

Comment: Do you perhaps mean power set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're asking whether $\mathcal{P}(E \cup F) = \mathcal{P}(E) \cup \mathcal{P}(F)$, where $E,F$ are sets and $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the power set operation, the answer in general is: no.

An element $X \in \mathcal{P}(E \cup F)$ is a subset $X \subseteq E \cup F$; however, an element $X \in \mathcal{P}(E) \cup \mathcal{P}(F)$ is either a subset $X \subseteq E$ or a subset $X \subseteq F$.

Thus elements of $\mathcal{P}(E) \cup \mathcal{P}(F)$ must be wholly contained in $E$ or wholly contained in $F$; this is not necessarily true of elements of $\mathcal{P}(E \cup F)$, unless there is a stronger condition on $E$ and $F$ (e.g. if $E \subseteq F$ or $F \subseteq E$).

For example, if $E = \{0, 1 \}$ and $F = \{ 1, 2 \}$, then $E \cup F = \{ 0, 1, 2 \}$, so $\{ 0, 2 \} \in \mathcal{P}(E \cup F)$ but $\{ 0, 2 \} \not \in \mathcal{P}(E) \cup \mathcal{P}(F)$.